# Programming a game controller

Tags: controller, pic

I looking to use a controller to operate an underwater robot.  I would like to use a joystick with several buttons.  I would like to program a pic and make my own circuit board.  I am not using a computer.  Where do I look to for help on programming a pic?

Thanks,

Cory

Comment: You are not using a computer??!?!?!?!

Comment: I think this falls outside the bounds of SO. Probably a better fit for [Electronics and Robots](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Get a [PICkit 3 programmer tool](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en538340), which includes a PIC programming tutorial and a CD with software for creating PIC programs.

You still need a computer to write and compile/assemble the source code, but afterwards this tool will let you download the binary to the chip.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Microchip.com they make the PIC processor. I would recommend you buy a PICKit 2 Starter kit. The PICKit 2 programmer has many features that the PICKit 3 does not. For example it can be used as a serial bus analyzer. This is very helpful in debugging projects if you don't have an oscilloscope. Additionally if you need help you can ask questions at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ they are like stack overflow but much more focus on embedded systems.